# How to achieve n levels of nested dynamic routes in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, routes, vue-router, nested-routes, dynamic-routing

I want to achieve n levels of dynamic nested routes in Vue.js, where n is unknown to me.
for eg -

```
abc.com/ctx-path/component/1/2/...../n
```

where 1,2,...n are the levels

How can I achieve this with Vue-router?

Answer (score 6):

Behind the scenes vue-router path matching uses [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp). 
So it should be possible to write something like this

```
{ path: '/ctx-path/component/:id+', component: Component }
```

or

```
{ path: '/ctx-path/component/:id*', component: Component }
```

You could also add path dynamically at [run time](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-addroutes), but you'll need to have a trigger to add it.

One last option is to have a [catch all route](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#catch-all-404-not-found-route) and add your own logic.

Comment: What you are suggesting is use of wildcard for regex matching. But what i want is to open different pages for different routes.  
for eg:

path: '/ctx-path/component/1/2/..../id1/.....n'

&

path: '/ctx-path/component/1/2/..../id2/.....n'


should open 2 different pages.

Comment: @Radu Diță  Maybe you can hep me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836601/how-can-make-dynamyc-routes-on-the-vue-router

Answer (score 0):

This is from docs:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/user/:id', component: User,
            children: [
                {
                // UserProfile will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
                // when /user/:id/profile is matched
                path: 'profile',
                component: UserProfile
                },
                {
                // UserPosts will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
                // when /user/:id/posts is matched
                path: 'posts',
                component: UserPosts
                }
            ]
       }
   ]
})
```

see link https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

Comment: the question is what if <profile> or <posts> in this example are ALSO dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Double dynamic nested routes to filter a single view by the nested URL params

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/category/:categoryId',
    name: 'category',
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "product" */ '../views/Categories.vue'),
    props: (route: Route) => ({
      categoryId: route.params.categoryId,
    }),
  },
  {
    path: '/category/:categoryId/:attributeIdsJsonString',
    name: 'attributeFilter',
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "product" */ '../views/Categories.vue'),
    props: (route: Route) => ({
      categoryId: route.params.categoryId,
      attributeIdsJsonString: route.params.attributeIdsJsonString,
    }),
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
});
```

Using different route names like this will mean that `beforeRouteUpdate` won't fire in some instances, so use `beforeRouteEnter` as well